# use config file of custom package without publishing in Laravel 5.*

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, package, config, publish

I have a *config* file for my Laravel Custom package.

Currently I am using *custom package's **config** file* by publishing it as mentioned in the *docs*.

I just want to clarify that, Is there a way to use custom package's *config* file without publishing it in *Laravel 5.**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved it.

Here's the code that I used.

```
public function register()
    {

        if ($this->app['config']->get('custom_package') === null) {
            $this->app['config']->set('custom_package', require __DIR__.'/../Config/config.php');
        }
```

in the `ServiceProvider` for the **custom package**.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `mergeConfigFrom` method of your package's ServiceProvider

```
/**
 * Register bindings in the container.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{
    $this->mergeConfigFrom(
        __DIR__.'/path/to/config/courier.php', 'courier'
    );
}
```